# How do I change the timezone of pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have PGAdmin hosted in server mode (container) on my server. In the "server activity" section, the time is being displayed in UTC. How do I make PGAdmin display time in my local time? I live in India and I want the Indian Time Zone (UTC+05:30). Symlinking `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata` to `/etc/localtime` doesn't work. I tried changing the `log_timezone` parameter to `UTC+05:30` in `postgresql.conf`, it doesn't work. Set the `timezone` parameter to `UTC+05:30`, did not work and also set `timezone_abbreviations` to `India`. That also did not work.